# How to store data in localstorage.setItem(); taht we can access anywhere in project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, cordova

Here I want to store `obj.email` in `localStorage.setItem("PMUsername", obj.email);` that I can access in my project anywhere. But I'm not able store the value, it's coming through as `null`.

```js
window.plugins.googleplus.login({}, function(obj) {
  console.log("Objct", obj);
  //$("#logs").append("<p class='success'><b>response: </b>" +localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(obj)) + "</p>")
  localStorage.setItem("value", JSON.stringify(obj));

  window.location.href = "login.html";

  document.querySelector("#image").src = obj.imageUrl;
  document.querySelector("#image").style.visibility = 'visible';

  // in below code am displaying email and username value in #feedback i.e <p id="feedback"></p>
  document.querySelector("#feedback").innerHTML = "Hi, " + obj.displayName + ", " + obj.email;
  localStorage.setItem("PMUsername", obj.email);
}, function(msg) {
  $("#logs").append("<p class='error'><b>response: </b>" + msg + "</p>");
});
}
```

I just need to store that `#feedback` value in `localstorage.getitem()`, so that I can access anywhere. Thanks

Comment: did you check the value obj.email in console?

Comment: yes..getting error- "email is not defined "

Comment: You cannot set `undefined` to the `localStorage`

Comment: if you are not getting email you cannot set it in localstorage. Make sure you are having email in console.. console.log("Objct", obj)

Comment: no value is coming in  localStorage.setItem("PMUsername", obj.email);

Comment: that undefined comes when i run in emulator ,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set `undefined` value to the `localStorage`.

You need to set a `string` to the `localStorage` as a value.

For this, your `obj` should contain property `email`.

Documentation on [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) can be helpful.

Comment: I know what is the reason for undefined value.. but it that syntax is ok.. but its not storing any value ,hard coded aslo

Comment: If you run the code:
`localStorage.setItem("PMUsername", 'test'); console.log(localStorage.getItem("PMUsername"));` what does it log in console? 
If you try to run this code in the browser console - you will get `test` printed.

Comment: main thing i want is I want get ("#feedback"). value in  localStorage.setItem("PMUsername")

Comment: You can get it with `document.querySelector("#feedback").innerText` or `document.querySelector("#feedback").innerHTML` and store it to the variable. Then just set this variable to the `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

if you are not getting email you cannot set undefined in localstorage.Make sure you are having email in console (console.log("Objct", obj))